# resolution of dell u3419w external monitor is aweful

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, dell, display-resolution

I tried to play around with several settings.
I am running a dell xps 13 dev with external monitor dell u3419w on ubuntu 18.04.

The resolution that the system has hardcoded by default in the settings is
2560x1440 (16:9) 
2560x1080 (21:9)
etc...

The problem is two-fold:
1) this is not the max configuration that the screen can provide. Yes, it is connected via displayport, which connects to the docking station where the monitor is connected via hdmi.

I am not a complete idiot. Here is what I tried.
The native resolution of the monitor is 3440 x 1440 at 60Hz.

```
 cvt 3440 1440 60
```

and got

```
 # 3440x1440 59.94 Hz (CVT) hsync: 89.48 kHz; pclk: 419.50 MHz Modeline "3440x1440_60.00"  419.50  3440 3696 4064 4688  1440 1443 1453 1493 -hsync +vsync
```

So, I tried to the usual via

```
 xrandr
```

And I was successfully able to add the native resolution to the "settings".

So from "settings" I picked the 2nd monitor (which is the DELL u3149w) and selected option

```
 3440 x 1440 (21:9)
```

However the resolution looks still horrible. Everything is stretched ... (yes it is a wide/curved monitor) ... but it looks unnatural ... as if it isn't the correct resoltuion. Under Windows 10, this resolution looks much better.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong ? Or what did I miss ?

Comment: update. this got resolved after I directly connected monitor to laptop via usb-c cable. My question now is though ... if I want to add another monitor (that is a 2nd external monitor) via DELL dockinstation (hdmi) ... I get snow on all three screens.

Comment: you should rewrite your entire question and the title then. if not people will just downvote and close. I don't know why you expected your hdmi cable to support 3440x1440, ....maybe the cable's the problem. different variants of display port on the other hand such as old display port, or the newer implementation : usb-c 3.0 have up to 5GB/s throughput (10 for 3.1 and 20 for 3.2) which should be enough. Now if you have three screens the bottleneck becomes the graphic card. see graphic cards with up to 5 outputs sometimes only support up to two displays anyways. this to me, is a hardware issue.